# How can I make a scrollbar only scroll at fixed intervals?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container div with fixed size and overflow: scroll, it's filled with smaller divs making a sort of list. here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/etYSC/2/

what I want is that the scrolling never cuts a box, making always 3 full boxes showing (in this example), so it will scroll always a fixed number of pixels.

How do I do this?

I'm using jquery library.

Google has been a harsh mistress on this question because of the misleading keywords.

**-- solution**

I was able to refine kiranvj code a bit more and I am very pleased with the final result.

**snapping the the previous div:**

```
var scrollTimerHandle = "";
var positionTimerHandle = "";

$("#container").scroll(function() {
    var boxSize = 84;   
    var newScrollPosition = parseInt(this.scrollTop / boxSize) * boxSize,
    _this = this;

    clearInterval(scrollTimerHandle);  
    scrollTimerHandle  = setTimeout(function() {
        positionTimerHandle = setInterval(function(){
          if (_this.scrollTop == newScrollPosition){
             clearInterval(positionTimerHandle);                   
          } else {
             _this.scrollTop--;
          }
        }, 5);         

    }, 600);   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etYSC/7/

**snapping to the closest div**

```
var scrollTimerHandle = "";
var positionTimerHandle = "";

$("#container").scroll(function() {
var boxSize = 84;    
var preScrollPosition = parseInt(this.scrollTop / boxSize) * boxSize;
var newScrollPosition = this.scrollTop - preScrollPosition < boxSize /2 
                             ? preScrollPosition : preScrollPosition + boxSize;
_this = this;

clearInterval(scrollTimerHandle);

    scrollTimerHandle  = setTimeout(function() {
        positionTimerHandle = setInterval(function(){      
          if (_this.scrollTop == newScrollPosition){
            clearInterval(positionTimerHandle);
          } else {
              if (_this.scrollTop > newScrollPosition){
                _this.scrollTop--;
              } else {
                _this.scrollTop++;  
              }          
          }
        }, 5);     

    }, 700);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etYSC/8/

Thanks for all the help, I was lost on how to aproach this and learned a good deal today.

Comment: This is a tough one, because if I'm not mistaken, you only inspect the scroll position *after* the scroll occurs. That means, if you force scrolling to be in increments (in this case, the height of your blocks), there will be a lot of stuttering as the container scrolls a few pixels, and then jumps back or forward. You could remove the scrollbar altogether and provide your own buttons that scroll the container in the desired increment.

Comment: @kiranvj got my final form, it isn't how I envisioned when I asked but I like this better. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a perfect solution.

But something like this should work (NB : need to refine)

```
​$("#container").scroll(function() {

   this.scrollTop = parseInt(this.scrollTop / 84) * 84; // 84 = height + top and bottom margin

});​​​
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/R7tAK/1/

**Update**

Some what refined code than the above, without any other plugins or libs. (flicker removed)

```
var scrollTimerHandle = "";

$("#container").scroll(function() {

var newScrollPosition = parseInt(this.scrollTop / 84) * 84,
    _this = this;

    clearInterval(scrollTimerHandle);

scrollTimerHandle  = setTimeout(function() {
   _this.scrollTop = newScrollPosition ;

}, 1000);


});​
```

Play here http://jsfiddle.net/R7tAK/4/

Comment: This is working like a charm, I'm pretty sure it will fit my code.Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I see a lot of jitter in the scroll, as I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer is very basic raw code, need to refine more and may add some surrounding logic. OR you need to add a custom scroll as and use some similar logic

Comment: Understood; my comment was aimed toward @petervaz

Comment: Little refined code added. @petervaz please check. @ jackwanders, I guess this is better than the previous.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably going to have to remove the scrollbar and use a Carousel, since you're using jQuery you can use the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) plugin. Here's an example using a [vertical carousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser but what need is too simple for adding this carousel to it and won't look right. This is a nice plugin, though.

Comment: The look of the carousel is completely up to how you style it, the example isn't the only way it has to look.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that replaces the scrollbar with some scroll buttons. I removed the scrollbar by setting `overflow:hidden;` on `#container`

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- your blocks --> 
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="scrollUp">Up</button>
    <button id="scrollDown">Down</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var container = $('#container');
var inc = 84;
$('#scrollUp').on('click',function(){
    container.scrollTop(container.scrollTop()-inc);
});        
$('#scrollDown').on('click',function(){
    container.scrollTop(container.scrollTop()+inc);
});
```

[**jsFidle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CbGta/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if i understand you right:

```
$("#container").scroll(function(){
        if($("#container").scrollTop()>=10) {
            $("#container").scrollTop(10);
        }
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnwsx/

Comment: That doesn't work; all it does is prevent the user from scrolling more than 10 pixels down the page.

Comment: That was not fully correct. But you can use scrollTop(x) to scroll down for fixed position.